# Express a predicate with given signature

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic

Consider $\mathbb{Z_+}$ as interpretation of a signature, which contains predicate of equality and predicate $x$ divides $y$ aka $x | y$. How do I express a predicate $\exists n\ x = 2^n$, if I add constant $2$ to my signature?

I think I should use predicate "$x = 1$" and predicate "$x$ - is a prime number", which I already expressed as the following:

$x = 1 \iff \forall z \ (x | z)$

$x$ - is a prime number $\iff \neg(\exists y(\neg(y = 1) \land \neg(y = x) \land y|x))$

Comment: I would use the simpler $$x \mbox{ is prime } \Leftrightarrow \forall a,b \ (x|ab \Rightarrow (x|a \lor x|b))$$ after that your predicate is simply $$\forall p \ ((p \mbox{ is prime } \wedge p|x) \Rightarrow p=2)$$

Comment: Do you use the multiplication symbol here $ab$? I'm not sure that you can simply write $a\cdot b$ with given signature.

Comment: Oh, you are right. Then, yours is the correct one.

Comment: Correct; the only "imperfection" is that in the def of $1$ you must have $x$ free also in the RHS : $x=1 \leftrightarrow \forall z \ (x|z)$.